# What is the maven dependency for Jetty 9 with SPDY feature?

Tags: java, maven, jetty

I want to setup jetty 9 with spdy feature in my Apache wicket java application. I am not getting correct maven dependencies for it.

Answer (score 1):

Dependency for Jetty with SPDY is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.spdy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spdy-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
</dependency>
```

List of all available versions you can find [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.spdy/spdy-jetty).

**Edit** after comment:

The `HTTPSPDYServerConnector` could be found here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty.spdy</groupId>
    <artifactId>spdy-jetty-http</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
</dependency>
```

And `WebAppContext`here:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
    <version>8.1.11.v20130520</version>
</dependency>
```

Just use search at http://mvnrepository.com to find any additional JARs.

Comment: Thanks Maksim for reply. I tried this dependency but still getting error for some classes like 'HTTPSPDYServerConnector', 'WebAppContext' etc..

Comment: I updated my answer to add dependencies for `HTTPSPDYServerConnector` and `WebAppContext`.